# How to access html element text in chrome devtools console

Tags: html, google-chrome-devtools

I have a page with a whole bunch of `blackquote` tags.
In dev console I am typing `document.getElementsByTagName("blockquote")` that giving me an array.

But if I do `document.getElementsByTagName("blockquote").innerText` `document.getElementsByTagName("blockquote").innerHTML` `document.getElementsByTagName("blockquote").textContent`
`document.getElementsByTagName("blockquote").outerText` `document.getElementsByTagName("blockquote").outerHTML`

All return `undefined`

However if I inspect elements of the array `document.getElementsByTagName("blockquote")` I can see all above properties in place.

How to access at least one of them (`innerText`, `outerHTLM`, `innerText`, `outerHTML`, `textContent`) ?

Comment: `$$('blockquote').map(e=>e.textContent)`

Comment: @wOxxOm  it could of be a great answer in case if I was using `jQuery`

Comment: It's not jQuery, it's built-in functionality of devtools command line API.

Comment: See the documentation: https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/console/command-line-reference

Comment: Also, jQuery doesn't have $$

Comment: @wOxxOm interesting.thanks for let me know.

Comment: Another useful hint: you can save the code in a *snippet* in the "sources" panel to easily run it later.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Or if you want to access any specific element you can use index in array

```
for (var i=0; i <document.getElementsByTagName("blockquote").length; i++ ){
    var singleElement = document.getElementsByTagName("blockquote")[i];
    console.log(singleElement.innerHTML);
}
```

Comment: you can use `singleElement.innerText` also

Answer (score 3):

You need to iterate the array in order to access those properties. Something like this will work for them:

```js
var elements = document.getElementsByTagName("blockquote");

for (var prop in elements)
{
  if(elements.hasOwnProperty(prop)) {
    console.log(elements[prop].innerHTML);
  }
}
```

Comment: yeah I wasnt sure actually that `.inner*` applied for each element. All you saying is make sense.

Comment: Yup those properties apply to individual elements. So all you need to do is to get those elements from the array. You can even do `document.getElementsByTagName("blockquote")[0].innerHTML` for the first element.

Comment: just did this `document.getElementsByTagName("blockquote").forEach(function(elem) { console.log(elem.innerHTML);});` - `forEach is not a function` - I think that is `jQuery` way as I do not have it on a page, getting the error.

Comment: My bad! You would need to access the elements using properties. `for(var prop in document.getElementsByTagName("blockquote"))` would work for this. Let me update my answer too.

Comment: why it is better to access the `prop` instead of just loop through the elements like @user4906240 advised?

Comment: why their answer is better? BTW I edited you answer but just ignore that as it makes the mode less readable.

Comment: Their answer could be improved if they used a variable to store the elements array rather than querying the elements twice. But `for` iterator is better in this case than a `for ..in`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/151936/discussion-between-nisarg-shah-and-sreginogemoh).

Answer (score 3):

You can also try the following commands:

`var elements = document.getElementsByTagName("blockquote");`.This will return the list of elements.To access the text of your required element at i index 
`elements[i].value`.

Answer (score 0):

For element text and text only, without any html information, working in 2023 Chrome 118.0.5993.8

```js
document.querySelectorAll("div.class").forEach((x) => {
    console.log(x.textContent);
});
```

You can also loop using

```js
for (var el in elements) {
  console.log(el.textContent) 
}
```